# sudo emacs crashes with tramp when I start a line with /

Tags: ssh, freeze, root, remote, emacs

I run emacs in command line [-nw] on ubuntu 12.04 as root.  If I start a line with '/', emacs freezes for a while and displays "Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell".

please note that I don't really know what tramp is.  (via google, it seems to open files through ssh).

Anyone know what this is, and how to stop it?

Comment: This probably depends on the configuration of your system, either your shell or your emacs init.el. check here for a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954479/emacs-tramp-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone was kind enough to answer this on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500805/every-time-i-type-a-comment-in-emacs-tramp-freezes-it

It turned out to be auto-complete.

Comment: nice points of views about programming languages :)